# Demultiplexing two pipes into one while keeping order

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that reads in a shell command, runs it and synchronously prints out it's stdout as white and stderr as red.
This would be useful for example when trying to log a script into one file while keeping track of what was an error and what not.

Currently I am using select() to convert the two pipes (stdout, stderr) from the shell command to one pipe while keeping the information from which file descriptor the char came from (in the struct collideC). Problem is that select sometimes selects multiple fd's (even though the timeout is NULL) and I don't know which has priority so the output characters are always in a different order.

The problem is caused here, basically:

```
if(select(nfds+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
   return -1;

int fdi = -1;

for(int i = 0; fds[i] != -1; ++i) {
   if(FD_ISSET(fds[i], &set)) {
      fdi = i;
      break;
   }
}
```

Even though `set` does sometimes contain more than one fds[i] I break after finding the first one, because I don't know in which order they should be printed anyway.

This is the console output (bold is red).

```
./logger 'echo one; echo two >&2; echo three'
one
three
t
```

There is no newline at the end.

Or sometimes the console output is:

```
one
three
two
```

With a newline at the end.

I also tried running two more threads, one that would process stdout and one for stderr, they both used `read()` blockingly, that also caused the same problem of synchronisation.

Code: https://pastebin.com/ee5Vcwm8

Comment: You will never be able to be 100% sure which output that came first, but you could make it more likely to process the output in the order it comes by dropping `select` and having one thread per descriptor doing a blocking read of 1 byte, followed by full buffer sized reads until a newline is found. Store everything after the newline for the next "return" and signal the main thread that the thread has a line ready. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Consider to use epoll. In epoll order of events is preserved.

Comment: @dimich In `epoll` the triggering mechanism would be the first byte and not when the line is complete - which may very well be what's wanted (my comment left that up to OP to decide). `epoll` is Linux specific if I remember correctly though. Does the posix `poll` provide the same guarantees?

Comment: @TedLyngmo epool will just indicate that pipe is readable. read() will return as much as available in pipe buffer (but not more than requested). I'm not sure `poll()` preserves order because it updates set of descriptors, not events. Another approach could be using pseudotty.